# Injection with google guice does not work anymore after obfuscation with proguard

Tags: obfuscation, guice, proguard

Has anyone ever tried to combine the use of google guice with obfuscation (in particular proguard)?
The obfuscated version of my code does not work with google guice as guice complains about missing type parameters. This information seems to be erased by the transformation step that proguard does, even when the relevant classes are excluded from the obfuscation.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Cannot inject a Provider that has no type parameter
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider
    for parameter 0 at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel.setPasswordPanelProvider(SourceFile:499)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel.setPasswordPanelProvider(SourceFile:499)
  while locating de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel
    for parameter 0 at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.b.k.setParentPanel(SourceFile:65)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.b.k.setParentPanel(SourceFile:65)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.o.a(SourceFile:38)

2) Cannot inject a Provider that has no type parameter
  while locating com.google.inject.Provider
    for parameter 0 at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel.setWindTurbineAccessGroupProvider(SourceFile:509)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel.setWindTurbineAccessGroupProvider(SourceFile:509)
  while locating de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.AdminUserCommonPanel
    for parameter 0 at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.b.k.setParentPanel(SourceFile:65)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.b.k.setParentPanel(SourceFile:65)
  at de.repower.lvs.client.admin.user.administration.o.a(SourceFile:38)

2 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:354)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.initializeStatically(InjectorBuilder.java:152)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
```

I tried to create a small example (without using guice) that seems to reproduce the problem:

```
package de.repower.common;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

class SomeClass<S> { 
}

public class ParameterizedTypeTest {

    public void someMethod(SomeClass<Integer> param) {
        System.out.println("value: " + param);
        System.setProperty("my.dummmy.property", "hallo");
    }

    private static void checkParameterizedMethod(ParameterizedTypeTest testObject) {
        System.out.println("checking parameterized method ...");
        Method[] methods = testObject.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("someMethod")) {
                System.out.println("Found method " + method.getName());
                Type[] types = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
                Type parameterType = types[0];
                if (parameterType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                    Type parameterizedType = ((ParameterizedType) parameterType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                    System.out.println("Parameter: " + parameterizedType);
                    System.out.println("Class: " + ((Class) parameterizedType).getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed: type ist not instance of ParameterizedType");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting ...");
        try {
            ParameterizedTypeTest someInstance = new ParameterizedTypeTest();
            checkParameterizedMethod(someInstance);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

If you run this code unsbfuscated, the output looks like this:

```
Starting ...
checking parameterized method ...
Found method someMethod
Parameter: class java.lang.Integer
Class: java.lang.Integer
```

But running the version obfuscated with proguard yields:

```
Starting ...
checking parameterized method ...
Found method someMethod
Failed: type ist not instance of ParameterizedType
```

These are the options I used for obfuscation:

```
-injars classes_eclipse\methodTest.jar
-outjars classes_eclipse\methodTestObfuscated.jar

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-printusage classes_eclipse\shrink.txt
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-verbose


-keep class **.ParameterizedTypeTest.class {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class ** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Keep names - _class method names. Keep all .class method names. This may be
# useful for libraries that will be obfuscated again with different obfuscators.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String,boolean);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this (apart from the obvious workaround to put the relevant files into a seperate jar and not obfuscate it)?

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 8):

Having used proguard for a good amount of time, here is how I decided to solve the issues regarding reflection (and Guice is only a use case of it).

Reflection can be used with Proguard as long as NO class or methods name are entered as Strings.

That's to say this code is valid and will work after ProGuard obfuscation

```
Class someClass = Class.forName(SomeClass.class.getName());
```

while this code won't work

```
Class someClass = Class.forName("SomeClass");
```

Furthermore, Proguard will shrink uncalled methods and constructor. As a consequence, the `Class.newInstance` method won't work. Unfortunatly, usual Guice bindings works using this method.

This has some consequences on Guice code.

- All your injections must be produced using @Provides annotated methods, since ProGuard will shrink classes due to the fact their constructors are not explictely called.
- Proguard must not shrink the code of your modules classes.
- ProGuard must not shrink annotations, whichever, and wherever they are (this can be configured, but I cannot remember where).

Comment: Wow, this is awful news that you have to use @Provides methods just to stop ProGuard from stripping the dependencies.  This begs for a tool to help.  I assume it would also work (almost equally annoyingly) to stick a bunch of -keep lines in the proguard config?

Comment: Maybe because adding the -keep annotation will make refactorings less effective, as we'll have to ensure in output jar that classes names are valid. To my mind, operating on a pure Java level makes our code more refactoring-compliant (if such a thing exists)

Answer (score 8):

The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher.

Use -keepattributes Signature to fix error with ParameterizedType

Comment: It didn't fix the problem from the example above. I still have to try it on my original problem with google guice.

Comment: This fixed it for me on android with the no-aop build, I was having the same issue as the OP. I also have the following in proguard config as well. -keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}

Comment: This worked for me too, with the same problem as the question asker had!!

Comment: I posted a bug report with a testcase here: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/518/ ... Its resolution will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the current version of Proguard (4.7) I was able to get it working by adding the following:-

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature  
-keep class com.google.inject.Binder    
-keep public class com.google.inject.Inject
 # keeps all fields and Constructors with @Inject
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <fields>;
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
```

In addition to explicitly keeping any class that is created by Guice eg

```
-keep class com.example.Service
```

Comment: This modification does not require explicitly adding your @Inject classes (which as noted in other posts is error prone):

`-keepclasseswithmembers,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation,allowoptimization class * {
    @com.google.inject.Provides <methods>;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me, having had the same problem.

`-keepattributes Signature` was the fix.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
#-dontobfuscate
-repackageclasses ''
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep class com.google.inject.Binder
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
} 

# I didn't need this one, maybe you need it.
#-keep public class roboguice.** 

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```